# Conflict to sorting and paginating functions in laravel-datatable

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am working on the data analytic project. I am using Laravel 5.6 and yajra/datatable (https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) library for a development. I am facing to the problems as follows:

Firstly, I created datatable from the query builder:

```
 $querybuilder = $mydb->getQuery($expression);
 return  Datatables::of($querybuilder)->make();
```

However, the orderBy() and take() function of Datatable lib conflict to my orderBy() and take() functions in my $querybuilder.

For example my `$querybuilder` is created from `$query->table(..)->where(..)->orderBy(second_column)->take(5)`

Because of `get()` function of `$querybuilder` did not be called beforehand so that after I put it into `Datatables::of($querybuilder)->make()` the query is controlled by Datatable lib so that orderBy() and take() is overwritten.

According to the result, I guess it is overwritten as follows:

```
$querybuilder->orderBy(first_column)->take(10);
```

Moreover, It also happens with search functions. The search function is searched on all records of the table but not first 5 records.

**My solution** in this case is change the *Query Builder* to *Collection*

Therefore, I used `Datatables::of($querybuilder->get())->make()` instead of `Datatables::of($querybuilder)->make()`

And it worked well in this case

**Unfortunately**, in the case I want to get all data from the database. The PHP will be **out of Memory** because of the data is too large and I get all of this as *Collection* before passing it to Datatable. If I give the data table the *Query Builder* it can handle the amount of data by paginate() function.

> Therefore, is there any way to solve both of those problems?

I really prefer to give Query Builder to Datatable than Collection because that way helps me saving the resource when getting a big data rather than changing the limitation of memory in PHP config. However, I do not know the solution to limit the data scope from my origin query after giving it to Datatable. Please help me if you know the solution.

Thank you in advance,